# laravel export PATH every time restart laptop

Tags: php, linux, laravel, homestead

I'm using mac Siera, I have to do this command before I can do `homestead up`

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Then I get:

> homestead command is not found error

Any clue?

Comment: add PATH to your `bash_profile` then

Comment: @AnarBayramov what's the command? What is the bash_profile?